# No DbContext was found in assembly when ruunung "dotnet ef migrations add"

Tags: linux, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a project that uses the code first approach and EntityFramework 5.0 and I'm willing to add migration by this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

Answer is

> " No DbContext was found in assembly 'stockmang'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic."

IS there a workaround for EF code first with DBContext?

Comment: You're really using EF5 with .Net Core?

Comment: Yeah, that is EF core syntax. IAC, make sure the project with the context is selected in the console or add parameters that tell it where it is.